# Pip install requirements in offline mode linux

Tags: python, pip

I am working in an **offline** Linux env. (RedHat 7.6)
until today I've used the full path to install
the files with pip, and it works great. (still, do)

Now on automated testing, I want to create a virtual 
environment and pip install a requirements file.

The problem is, it keeps searching the web,
even though I've used `--prefix`, and tried `--target`
I can't get it to install from a certain folder,
always try to search the web

requirements file:

```
numpy==1.16.4
```

folder:

```
/custom_dev/install/
```

inside the folder:

```
numpy-1.16.4-cp37-37m-manylinux_x86_64.whl
```

tried:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target=/custom_dev/install/
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --prefix=/custom_dev/install/
```

and other stuff from StackOverflow, I've yet to find a solution to my problem, or a thread with the same one, suggestions?

ty!

Comment: How about `pip install /custom_dev/install/*.whl`?

Comment: you are my hero @KlausD.

Answer (score 2):

Our `pip-local` does that:

```
c:\srv\bin> cat pip-local.bat
@echo off
rem pip install with `--upgrade --no-deps --no-index --find-links=file:///%SRV%/wheelhouse`

pip %* --upgrade --no-deps --no-index --find-links=file:///%SRV%/wheelhouse
```

the linux version uses `$*` instead of `%*` and `$SRV` instead of `%SRV%`:

```
pip $* --upgrade --no-deps --no-index --find-links=file:///${SRV}/wheelhouse
```

You can remove the `--no-deps` if you want dependencies to be found as well (although it will search the web if it can't find a wheel satisfying a dependency in your wheelhouse).

The companion tool is `getwheel`

```
c:\srv\bin> cat getwheel.bat
@echo off
rem
rem Download wheel file for  package (getwheel foo==1.4.1)
rem

pip wheel --wheel-dir=%SRV%\wheelhouse %*
```

linux version:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=${SRV}/wheelhouse $*
```

which is used like:

```
getwheel numpy==1.16.4
```

or

```
getwheel -r requirements.txt
```

which causes the wheels of the package and its dependencies to be placed in the wheelhouse folder.

Comment: i didn't manage to work with you explanation , rem is not supported on my platform, and getwheel.bat , pip-local.bat do not exist

Comment: I've updated my answer with the linux equivalents. `getwheel` and `pip-local` are script files that we've created as shortcuts for the commands listed inside. We develop on windows, so they're windows .bat files (`rem` means that the rest of the line is a comment, ie. the same as `#` does in bash).

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --find-links=/custom_dev/install/ --no-index
```

The keyword to prevent `pip` to connect to PyPI via the network is `--no-index`.